# Is this interpretation of a division algebra correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra): "We call D a division algebra if for any element a in D and any non-zero element b in D there exists precisely one element x in D with a = bx and precisely one element y in D such that a = yb."

I just want to confirm that what I think is right: This is the same as saying that every element has both a (unique) left inverse and a right inverse, right?

Comment: Yes.... $~~~~~~~$

Comment: ... and if you assume that $D$ is associative (as people often but not always do), then the usual argument shows that the left and right inverses coincide.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the comment. If every element has a left inverse doesn't this imply that  the division algebra has a $1$ (the multiplicative identity)? In the Wikipedia article this seems to not necessarily be the case. I am confused.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Then I wanted to see a different definition and found [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionAlgebra.html) and it seems to imply that a skew field is the same as a division algebra. I'm not sure this is true because an algebra (over some field) seems to have more structure than a skew field.

Comment: You're right in that for the inverse to make sense there has to be a $1$. Many authors define that a division algebra should be associative, but not everybody agrees. The octonions are a case in point. I'm not sure whether there is any difference between a division algebra and a skew field. The structure of an algebra sounds like it is a bit extra, but that is a bit fuzzy, too. After all, a skew field is an algebra over its center (or any subfield of the center).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your comment.